# Printing a rectangle - I want an additional print but I can't get it work

Tags: java, for-loop, printing, syntax

Made an own task for me to learn programming in java, about printing in particular.

As example, we have input `8`. Then we must get as output a rectangle made of "+", so it would look like this:

```
++++++++
+      +
+      +
+      +
+      +
+      +
+      +
+      +
++++++++
```

The following code will do this (if you want me to explain it, please tell me and I will do it):

```
public class Printest{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            System.out.print("+");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i=0; i<x-1; i++){
            System.out.print("+");
            for(int j=0; j<x-2; j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("+");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
            System.out.print("+");
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want add an additional feature so there is a cross inside of this square, how can I do it? I have tried to add some if-statements but I always ended up shifting the rectangles left and right edges.. : /

I want it looks like this to be more precise:

```
+++++++++
+*     *+
+ *   * +
+  * *  +
+   *   +
+  * *  +
+ *   * +
+*     *+
+++++++++
```

How would you do it? if-statements doesn't seem to work and I have the feeling it's not possible to implement this in my code because of the multiple, separate for-loops..?

By the way, is there maybe a much easier way to get this work (just print the rectangle)? I think I took a very complicated and unefficient way. I would be very interested in knowing easier ways, if they aren't more complicated :P

Comment: hint: two for loops adding the stars from the second row second column to one before the last row and column of the rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By the way, is there maybe a much easier way to get this work (just print the rectangle)? I think I took a very complicated and unefficient way.

Actually yes! You can do it with 2 `for` loops:

```
public class RectangleWithShapesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 8;

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == number - 1) {
                    System.out.print("+");
                } else {
                    if (j == 0 || j == number - 1) {
                        System.out.print("+");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

That alone, prints the rectangle of size 8, then, if you add this `else-if` statement:

```
else if (i == j || i == (number - j - 1)) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

The first condition above tells your program to print a `*` diagonal like this: `\` (that orientation), and the second one, evaluates it to print it in the other direction (`/`)

You can print the `*` cross, so, in the end your whole program looks like this:

```
public class RectangleWithShapesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 9;

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == number - 1) {
                    System.out.print("+");
                } else {
                    if (j == 0 || j == number - 1) {
                        System.out.print("+");
                    } else if (i == j || i == (number - j - 1)) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

And it's output is:

```
++++++++
+*    *+
+ *  * +
+  **  +
+  **  +
+ *  * +
+*    *+
++++++++
```

And with 9 elements:

```
+++++++++
+*     *+
+ *   * +
+  * *  +
+   *   +
+  * *  +
+ *   * +
+*     *+
+++++++++
```

As a suggestion, I recommend you to space a little your operation signs from your variables to make your code a little more readable and make your variables more descriptive (`x` to `number` for example)

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, I have troubles imagining these for-loops that come after the other, let me try to draw it :D

Comment: Imagine those inner loops like if you're in a chess board, you'll go through one row, and when you reach the end of it, you "jump" to the one below and start over, it's the same logic

Answer (score 0):

You need to find relationships between the corners of the cross/star. Take this star for example of size 5.

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 *       *
1   *   *
2     *
3   *   *
4 *       *
```

In a cross in the diagonal from (0,0) to (4,4), indices are the same (in the code this means `row == col`).

Also, you can notice that in the diagonal from (0,4) to (4,0) indices always sum up to 4, which is `size - 1` (in the code this is `row + col == size - 1`).

Therefore in the code, you will need to loop through rows and then through columns. Each time you have to check if the above conditions are fufilled.

For the `+` border simply check when either `row` or `col` is `0`, and also when equal to `size - 1`.

Lastly you print the border first so the corners of the cross are not `*` but rather `+`.

**Code:**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printCross(8); //Vertical size of rectangle/cross
  }

  public static void printCross(int size) {
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        if (row == 0 || col == 0 || row == size - 1 || col == size - 1)
          System.out.print('+');
        else if (row == col || row + col == size - 1)
          System.out.print('*');
        else
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Eu0v/0)

Comment: Thank you very much also for answer, trying to understand it I think you both solved it same / similar :)