# How to fulfill diagonal in array in 75% with number 1, and the rest (25%) with number -1?

Tags: java

I have to code function that create two-dimensional array of Integer numbers with random size from [50, 100] and divisible by 4. Number of rows is equal to number of columns. Next, an array is fulfill with random numbers (except elements that are on diagonal) from range [a, b), where a and b are enter by user.

Values on diagonal have got fulfill in random arrangement in 75% by number 1, and the rest of 25% with number -1.

Functions, should print-out to console amount of cells which value is less than product of index from row and column these cell.

I have no idea how to deal with these diagonals and amount of cells...

So far I come off with something like this:

```
public static void createArray()
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int drawed = 1, rows, cols;

    while (drawed %4 != 0)
    {
        drawed = 50 + generator.nextInt(51);
    }
    rows = drawed;
    cols = rows;

    int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];

    System.out.println("Input a: ");
    int a = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Input b: ");
    int b = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
                array[i][j] = a + generator.nextInt(b - a);
        }
}
```

How to fulfill diagonal in 75% with number 1, and the rest (25%) with number -1? 
How count cells which value is less than product from index of rows and columns?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to fulfill diagonal in 75% with number 1, and the rest (25%) with number -1? And how count cells which value is less than product from index of rows and columns?

Comment: You should add that to your question instead of posting it as a comment. Futhermore, Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea how to deal with these diagonals

First, let's try to draw a diagonal of any char, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250389/2180785)

Basically you have to know when the indexes belong to the diagonal or not, this can be done with some logic, let's use a `N x N` board where `N = 8`:

```
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2] [0][3] [0][4] [0][5] [0][6] [0][7]
[1][0] [1][1] [1][2] [1][3] [1][4] [1][5] [1][6] [1][7]
[2][0] [2][1] [2][2] [2][3] [2][4] [2][5] [2][6] [2][7]
[3][0] [3][1] [3][2] [3][3] [3][4] [3][5] [3][6] [3][7]
[4][0] [4][1] [4][2] [4][3] [4][4] [4][5] [4][6] [4][7]
[5][0] [5][1] [5][2] [5][3] [5][4] [5][5] [5][6] [5][7]
[6][0] [6][1] [6][2] [6][3] [6][4] [6][5] [6][6] [6][7]
[7][0] [7][1] [7][2] [7][3] [7][4] [7][5] [7][6] [7][7]
```

There is a pattern there for the diagonals: can you see it?

- `\`: **Row and column are the same number**
- `/` **Row = number - column - 1**

> How to fulfill diagonal in 75% with number 1, and the rest (25%) with number -1?

You need to know how many numbers you're gonna use, but... you already know that! Remember `N`? Well we're going to use a formula to know what is `75%` of `N`:

- `75% of N = N * 75 / 100`
- `25% of N = N * 25 / 100`

In our case using `N = 8` that becomes:

- 8 * 75 = 600 / 100 = 6
- 8 * 25 = 200 / 100 = 2

Then create your own function which returns either `1` or `-1` based on how many positive or negative numbers you've added already as in the code below

> How count cells which value is less than product from index of rows and columns?

That, in code means that you need to know how many values are less than `i * j`

```
if (array[i][j] < i * j) {
    count++;
}
```

Joining everything (without using a Scanner as I'm lazy for that):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SquareDiagonalNumbers {
    private static int positive = 0;
    private static int negative = 0;

    private static int n = 8;

    private static int positiveOnes = n * 75 / 100; //75%
    private static int negativeOnes = n * 25 / 100; //25%

    private static int a = 10;
    private static int b = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[n][n];

        int products = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                array[i][j] = i == j || i == (n - j - 1) ? randomOnes() : randomNumber();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] < i * j) {
                    products++;
                    System.out.println("At [" + i + ", " + j + "] number " + array[i][j] + " is lower than [i * j]: " + (i * j));
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total of numbers lower than the product of their row and column: " + products);
    }

    private static int randomNumber() {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt(b - a) + a;
    }

    private static int randomOnes() {
        Random r = new Random();
        boolean isPositive = r.nextBoolean();

        if (isPositive) {
            if (positive < positiveOnes) {
                positive++;
                return 1;
            } else {
                negative++;
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (negative < negativeOnes) {
                negative++;
                return -1;
            } else {
                positive++;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces a similar output to this:

```
-1 17 14 19 14 19 14 -1 
11 1 11 18 18 14 1 14 
11 14 1 14 12 1 17 13 
16 10 12 1 1 12 10 11 
11 11 14 -1 1 19 14 19 
15 12 -1 19 14 1 13 15 
13 -1 17 10 12 12 1 10 
1 19 15 18 12 11 13 1 
At [0, 0] number -1 is lower than [i * j]: 0
At [0, 7] number -1 is lower than [i * j]: 0
At [1, 6] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 6
At [2, 2] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 4
At [2, 5] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 10
At [2, 7] number 13 is lower than [i * j]: 14
At [3, 3] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 9
At [3, 4] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 12
At [3, 5] number 12 is lower than [i * j]: 15
At [3, 6] number 10 is lower than [i * j]: 18
At [3, 7] number 11 is lower than [i * j]: 21
At [4, 3] number -1 is lower than [i * j]: 12
At [4, 4] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 16
At [4, 5] number 19 is lower than [i * j]: 20
At [4, 6] number 14 is lower than [i * j]: 24
At [4, 7] number 19 is lower than [i * j]: 28
At [5, 2] number -1 is lower than [i * j]: 10
At [5, 4] number 14 is lower than [i * j]: 20
At [5, 5] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 25
At [5, 6] number 13 is lower than [i * j]: 30
At [5, 7] number 15 is lower than [i * j]: 35
At [6, 1] number -1 is lower than [i * j]: 6
At [6, 3] number 10 is lower than [i * j]: 18
At [6, 4] number 12 is lower than [i * j]: 24
At [6, 5] number 12 is lower than [i * j]: 30
At [6, 6] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 36
At [6, 7] number 10 is lower than [i * j]: 42
At [7, 3] number 18 is lower than [i * j]: 21
At [7, 4] number 12 is lower than [i * j]: 28
At [7, 5] number 11 is lower than [i * j]: 35
At [7, 6] number 13 is lower than [i * j]: 42
At [7, 7] number 1 is lower than [i * j]: 49
Total of numbers lower than the product of their row and column: 32
```

Comment: Geeez! Dude, thank you very much, this's exactly what I need for understand this, sample with explanation, thanks one more time!

Comment: @l1m4k For further questions I recommend you to: Divide and conquer, try to solve one simple problem at a time, instead of a big one problem at once. Please read [ask] until you get familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I could not understood your last point of displaying the output to console. However the following program will solve the problem you are facing for diagonal values.

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doJob(12, 20, 200);

    }

    private static void doJob(int size, int a, int b) {
        if (size % 4 == 0) {

            int[][] array = new int[size][size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

                    if (i != j && (i + j) != (size - 1))
                        array[i][j] = generateRandomNumber(a, b);

                }
            }

            int positiveOneSize = calculateLocationRequiredForOne(size * 2);
            int negetiveOneSize = (size - 1) - positiveOneSize;

            /* Fill the diagonals with random values for positive one */

            while (positiveOneSize > 0 || negetiveOneSize > 0) {

                int location = generateRandomNumber(0, size - 1); // Random loc
                int posOrNeg = generateRandomNumber(0, 2);
                if (posOrNeg == 0) {

                    array[location][location] = 1;
                    array[location][(size - 1) - location] = 1;

                } else {
                    array[location][location] = -1;
                    array[location][(size - 1) - location] = -1;

                }
                positiveOneSize--;
                negetiveOneSize--;
            }

            /* Print array */

            for (int m = 0; m < size; m++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < size; n++) {
                    System.out.print(" " + array[m][n]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    private static int generateRandomNumber(int a, int b) {
        return a + (int) (Math.random() * ((b - a) + 1));
    }

    private static int calculateLocationRequiredForOne(int size) {
        return (int) (0.75 * size);
    }

}
```